# How can I fix an "IOException: Stream closed" exception using System.in?

Tags: java, ioexception, system.in

I'm writing a simple program that reads and processes file content using a `BufferedReader`.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in) );

System.out.println("Enter the file name to read");
String fileName = br.readLine();
br.close();

// Process file contents

br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in) );
System.out.println("Enter another file name to read");
fileName = br.readLine();
br.close();
```

But when I call second `br.readLine()` to read another file name, I get the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Stream closed

I don't understand how the `System.in` stream can be closed.
What mistake am I making and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The stream is closed because you're closing it with the first

```
br.close();
```

that you issue after having read the filename.

Don't close that reader, and don't create a new one for `System.in` - just re-use that one. Use a different one for reading from the file though.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that.
But is there any way that I can use the same buffered reader?
This is just out of curiosity.